# LVM - Renaming a Volume Group and ensuring system can boot?

Tags: linux, centos, partition, lvm, volume

I have a fresh install of CentOS 7, which will act as a KVM host.

I don't like the default name given to the Volume Group and I'd like to change it.

I read somewhere that renaming volume group that contains logical volume for / can cause cause system to not boot after reboot. Why is this by the way?

I've seen some guides but I wanted to check here. What are the steps to make sure a system will survive reboot after changing volume group name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When using LVM, the RHEL/CentOS 7 initramfs generator seems to auto-generate the `root=` option that specifies the device containing the root filesystem. And the generated entry will be of the form `root=/dev/mapper/VGname-LVname`.

There are also one or two other boot options that will specify the LV(s) to activate within the initramfs phase: the LV for the root filesystem, and the LV for primary swap (if you have swap on a LV). These options are of the form `rd.lvm.lv=VGname/LVname`.

If you rename the VG containing the root filesystem while the OS is running, you will encounter a problem using `grub2-mkconfig` to update the GRUB configuration:

```
/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/oldVGname-rootLVname'
```

Although the VG has been renamed, the old pathnames still appear in `/proc/mounts`, and `grub2-mkconfig` will fail to detect the new root filesystem device name.

So, when renaming the root VG on RHEL/CentOS 7, you'll need to perform four tasks:

- Modify the kernel boot options to use the new name (`rd.lvm.lv=` and `root=` if it exists) in `/etc/default/grub`, but **don't run `grub2-mkconfig`**
- Modify the same kernel boot options directly in the actual GRUB configuration file (`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` in systems with BIOS/MBR style boot; `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` booting in UEFI native style). There will be multiple kernel entries to edit: be careful to change them all.
- Update any `/etc/fstab` entries referring to the VG by name to use the new name.
- Use `vgrename` to rename the VG.

The order of these tasks is not important, but all of these need to be accomplished (or reverted) before rebooting the system. And you probably should reboot pretty soon after making these changes: the remaining references to the old root VG name in `/proc/mounts` etc. might confuse some system tools.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough if the boot command line (linux ...) uses UUID instead of /dev/sysvg/root_lv.